# VBox network mode to test Win 2008 server?

Tags: dns, virtualbox, dhcp

I have 2 machines running on my VirtualBox, one is a Windows XP client the second one is a 2008 Server with DHCP and DNS installed and configured.

now i want to test my server setup with my client machine, i tried all the network mode in VirtualBox but none of them worked

- NAT mode get dhcp setting from VirtualBox itself i think
- Bridged mode get dhcp from my router

...

any idea what should i do ?

Comment: What specifically are you hoping to test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first guess would be to configure both virtual machines to have a single virtual network adapter that is configured as "internal network" and set a static IP address on both virtual machines. That will effectively isolate both guests to their own private network for testing.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you to set network adapters on both virtual machines in "Bridge Mode".

On Windows Server 2008 you must choose type: **Intel PRO/1000 MT Server (82545EM)**

In this way, your virtual machine will get an IP address on the same LAN of your host machine, and the three machines can communicate